# Trouble with class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a label within a class and I'm getting an error when i try to do the following code below where its bold. The error I'm getting is that

> `Drawing` is not declared. It may be due to its protection level.

I'm thinking that I have to import a namespace, but I'm not sure exactly which one contains `Drawing`. I have researched this and have been unsuccessful. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Label1.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
```

Comment: Short but complete code samples are always appreciated - as it is, we have *no* context for this line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Color` is actually [`System.Drawing.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx).

You can fully qualify it:

```
lable1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

Alternatively, you can use `Imports System.Drawing` at the top of your file:

```
' This needs to be in your imports: Imports System.Drawing
lable1.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: In VB.NET, you don't need to fully qualify a name; if `System` is imported, you can use `Drawing.Color.Red` without problems.

Comment: @minitech Yes - but it obviously wasn't - typically, though, the two options I listed are the more common ones...

Comment: It didnt work at first but then I had to add it as a reference the reference system.drawing and then it worked. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` in your project? If you don't, add it using Project > Add Reference. Otherwise, you may need to import `System` using this statement at the top of your file:

```
Imports System
```

Though by default, in a Windows Forms Application, there is a reference to `System.Drawing` and it's imported, too. Finally, your capitalization is wrong; it should be `Label1.ForeColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Creates a label within a class and then changes the ForeColor to red.

```
    Dim bar As New foo
    bar.myLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
    'or
    bar.myLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    'or
    bar.myLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red



Class foo
    Property myLabel As New Label
End Class
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does that mean?

Comment: Maybe you know me, I was wondering :) Anyway, I meant that I didn't understand what the block of code meant.